# How do I bulk enable Google Ads campaigns using Google Ads script?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I have 700+ campaigns that I want to enable in a Google Ads account. How can I achieve that using Google Ads script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Google Ads script that takes an array of campaign IDs and enables all the campaigns:

```
function enableCampaigns(campaignIds) {
    var campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns().withIds(campaignIds).get();
    while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
        campaign.enable();
        Logger.log("Campaign '" + campaign.getName() + "' with ID " +
        campaign.getId() + " has been enabled.");
    }
}


function main() {
    var campaignIds = ['REPLACE THIS WITH THE CAMPAIGN ID', 'REPLACE THIS WITH THE CAMPAIGN ID', ...];
    enableCampaigns(campaignIds);

}
```